# How to show error message in modal dialog from ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, modal-dialog, fluentvalidation

I have ASP.NET Core MVC project. In my core project, I am using fluent validation like this:

```
public class AddEntityViewModelValidator: AbstractValidator<AddEntityViewModel>
{
    public AddEntityViewModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("You must enter name.");
    }
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateEntity(AddEntityViewModel addEntityViewModel)
{
    try
    {                
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {                    
            var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage)).ToList();
            foreach(var error in errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error: ", error);
            }
                    
            return View(addEntityViewModel);
        }

        await _businessLogic.CreateEntity(addEntityViewModel.Entity);
        return View(addEntityViewModel);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return View(addEntityViewModel);
    }
}
```

When user doesn't enter the name in model dialog, fluent validation do the work. This list of errors (var errors in controller) contains this error, so this part is working. But in my cshmtl modal-dialog this error message is not showing anywhere.

I have the the button for opening modal dialog:

```
<div id="PlaceHolderHere"></div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-target="#addEntity"
        data-url="@Url.Action("AddEntity", "Entity", new { entityId = Model.Id})">
    Add entity
</button>
```

and my jquery code:

```
$(function () {
    var PlaceHolderElement = $('#PlaceHolderHere');
    $('button[data-toggle="ajax-modal"]').click(function (event) {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        var decodeUrl = decodeURIComponent(url);
        $.get(decodeUrl).done(function (data) {
            PlaceHolderElement.html(data);
            PlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
        })
    })

    PlaceHolderElement.on('click', '[data-save="modal"]', function (event) {
        var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
        var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
        var sendData = form.serialize();
        $.post(actionUrl, sendData).done(function (data) {
            PlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
            location.reload(true);
        })
    })
})
```

Here is my modal-dialog:

```
@model AddEntityViewModel

<div class="modal fade" id="addEntity">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h2 class="modal-title" id="addEntityLabel">@Model.Title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">                
                <form action="CreateEntity">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger wrapper"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="@Model.Entity.Name">Name</label>
                        <input asp-for="@Model.Entity.Name" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Entity.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>                    
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-save="modal">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, i have this line:

`<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger wrapper"></div>`

but error is still now showing. Any idea how to solve this? Should I change something in my jquery function?

Comment: You have modal body, but I think you are missing modal triggering tags, usually a button with attribute `data-toggle="modal"` and target attribute `data-target="#addEntity"` telling Bootstrap's script which exactly modal should be opened when user hits the trigger button. You can also open the model via JavaScript `$('#addEntity').modal('show')`. Read more about working with modals in [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#live-demo).

Comment: @Prolog My modal dialog is opened, but when my controller returns error like this "You must enter name.", the error doesn't apper on the modal dialog.

Comment: @Prolog I edited my question, I hope that is more precise now.

Comment: You should try to use "Form Helper" with "Fluent Validation". They work well together. https://github.com/sinanbozkus/FormHelper

You can easily show your messages on the screen.

Comment: Can you post the `AddEntityViewModel` class? From the model-dialog view source, it seems that it contains an `Entity` property. Besides, according to your code, it seems that you are using two views to add an entity, the modal-dialog trigger button is on the Main page and it will open the Modal-dialog view in the popup modal, right? In my opinion, I suggest you could try to put the modal-dialog related code in the main page, then, using jquery to add the partial view to the modal content, if you agree to use this method, I will try to create a sample for you.